# Современный графический интерфейс

Tags: c++builder, windows, c++

Здравствуйте.

Я программирую в среде C++ Builder 6.0 (опыт есть, но небольшой). Как известно, любые компоненты, по умолчанию, имеют внешний вид вроде обычных кнопок Windows 98, тогда как прогресс не стоит на месте и внешний вид кнопок, например Vista уже другой... в связи с этим вопрос.

Как к проекту подключить вид элементов, которые используется в системе. Или если все не так просто, то как называется то, что я должен почитать по теме?

Comment: Проще всего будет поставить Embarcadero RAD Studio 2010, тот же билдер от борланда.

Answer (score 1):

- [**Манифесты**](http://www.sources.ru/cpp/faqs/46.htm) универсальны и, естественно, работают для компонентов `VCL`, поскольку стайлинг происходит на уровне ОС.
- Альтернативный вариант - использовать чистый `WinAPI`, тогда нужно смотреть в сторону метода [**InitCommonControlsEx.**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775697(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[AlphaControls](http://www.alphaskins.com/index_rus.php). Можете еще использовать эти скины.